# How to push to view in tabbar with some data in a variable?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an tabbar which includes:
    TabBar
        - HomeView -> UserProfileView -> Gallery
        - LeaderBoardView
        - SettingView
        - ........
Here, from homeview, user can go to userProfileView to select various options(camera, gallery, avatar) to change user profile in homeview.
Let's say, user choose gallery, he/she goes to gallery, choose image and the code will push back to homeview, with image. The user profile image will change, but the tab bar controllers got disappeared. It's same case with choosing avatar too.

It is not possible to push to tabbar view since, we need the image to be in homeview, because variable for image is in homeview. Can we push to tabbar view and image data in homeview?? Or can we push to homeview and keep tab bar controllers shown.

[image]

I am new to xcode/Swift. I am trying to make a quiz app as a practice.
 I have used

```
NavigationController.pushviewController
```

Here are some code that refers to the problem.

```
    fileprivate func presentPhotoPickerController() {
        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.allowsEditing = true
        myPickerController.delegate = self
        myPickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(myPickerController, animated: true)
    }

@IBAction func goToGalleryBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary){
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
                switch status {
                case .authorized:
                    self.presentPhotoPickerController()
                    break
                case .notDetermined:
                    if status == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized{
                        self.presentPhotoPickerController()
                    }
                case .restricted:
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Photo Library Restricted", message: "Photo Library access is restricted and cannot be accessed.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
                    alert.addAction(okAction)
                    self.present(alert, animated: true)
                case .denied:
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Photo Library Denied", message: "Photo Library access was previously denied. Please update your Settings if you wish to change this.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let goToSettingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Go to Settings", style: .default){(action) in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!
                            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
                        }
                    }
                    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
                    alert.addAction(goToSettingsAction)
                    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
                    self.present(alert, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func cancelBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension UserAvatarViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage{
            imageGallery = image
        }else if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage{
            imageGallery = image
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "HomeViewController", bundle: nil)
        let homeVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! HomeViewController
        homeVC.imageView = imageGallery
//        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeVC, animated: true)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

By the way, I have used different storyboards to every view controller.

Comment: can you post the body of method `self.presentPhotoPickerController()`

Comment: Oh I missed that part to copy.... :). I have updated the code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage{
        imageGallery = image
    }else if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage{
        imageGallery = image
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    let storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TabBarViewController", bundle: nil)
    let tabBarVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarVC") as! UITabBarController
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarVC
    let navBar = tabBarVC.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
    let homeVC = navBar.topViewController as! HomeViewController
    homeVC.imageView = imageGallery
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

This finally worked. Thanks Hisenberg and Najeeb ur Rehman for giving me tips on using Tab bar view controller and its children.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your issue is with `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method.
Instead of picking up the controller from tabbar, you are creating a new object of `HomeViewController`
I assume you have set the `tabbarcontroller` as the `rootviewcontroller` on the window.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage{
        imageGallery = image
    }else if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage{
        imageGallery = image
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let tabbar = appDel.window.rootViewController as TabbarViewController
    // if you know the index of the controller on tabbar, you can directly access it 
    let homeVC = tabbar.viewControllers[0] as! HomeViewController
    homeVC.imageView = imageGallery
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Let me know how did you set your `tabbar` if its not the window's `rootViewController`

Comment: Tabbar is not root view controller. It comes after user login page.

Comment: so post login, you push a tabbarcontroller in a navigationcontroller?

Comment: It would be a rational approach to set the window's rootviewcontroller as tabbarcontroller, as post login, controller will not be revisited

Comment: I used above solution and it gave me error like: Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' . So, I add some navigation controller and push to homeview.                                                                                                                 if let navTbar = tabbar.viewControllers{
            let navBar = navTbar[0] as! UINavigationController .  let homeVC = navBar.viewControllers[0] as! HomeV..                  
 And in homeview, in view did appear, I updated the image to show. It shows the image, but the tabbar problem is still there. It gets disappeared.

Comment: Try `myPickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext` in `presentPhotoPickerController()` method

Comment: let storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TabBarViewController", bundle: nil)
        let tabBarVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarVC") as! UITabBarController
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarVC    Using this, I can return back to tab bar controller successfully. But there is error for passing image because, homeview is in different storyboard (made using storyBoard reference). So, I am wondering, how to pass image in different storyboards inside tabbar.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `imagePickerController(picker: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo)` method like this

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage{
        imageGallery = image
    }else if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage{
        imageGallery = image
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    //Assuming your viewcontroller hierarchy is
    // TabbarVC -> HomeVC -> GalleryVC -> ImagePickerVC
    if let homeVC = self.parent as? HomeViewController {
        homeVC.imageView = imageGallery
    }

    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

And update the image in `viewWillAppear` of `HomeViewController`.
Hope it will serve your purpose.

Comment: `instantiateViewController` will create a new tabbar, resetting the state of all the controllers in it. Grab the previously created tabbar object and update the properties.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I was about to update it but you have mentioned it. BTW thanks.